# Disabling ssh password authentication

Tags: authentication, ssh, passwords

I am trying to disable password authentication with ssh, but it doesn't seem to be working.  I have followed every set of directions I can find to fix this, and they're all basically the same.  I have modified the /etc/ssh/ssh_config files as follows:

```
# This is the ssh client system-wide configuration file.  See
# ssh_config(5) for more information.  This file provides defaults for
# users, and the values can be changed in per-user configuration files
# or on the command line.

# Configuration data is parsed as follows:
#  1. command line options
#  2. user-specific file
#  3. system-wide file
# Any configuration value is only changed the first time it is set.
# Thus, host-specific definitions should be at the beginning of the
# configuration file, and defaults at the end.

# Site-wide defaults for some commonly used options.  For a comprehensive
# list of available options, their meanings and defaults, please see the
# ssh_config(5) man page.

Host *
#   ForwardAgent no
#   ForwardX11 no
#   ForwardX11Trusted yes
#   RhostsRSAAuthentication no
#   RSAAuthentication yes
#   PubKeyAuthentication yes
#   PasswordAuthentication no
#   HostbasedAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
#   GSSAPIKeyExchange no
#   GSSAPITrustDNS no
#   BatchMode no
#   CheckHostIP yes
#   AddressFamily any
#   ConnectTimeout 0
#   StrictHostKeyChecking ask
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/identity
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa
#   Port 22
#   Protocol 2,1
#   Cipher 3des
#   Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
#   MACs hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160
#   EscapeChar ~
#   Tunnel no
#   TunnelDevice any:any
#   PermitLocalCommand no
#   VisualHostKey no
#   ProxyCommand ssh -q -W %h:%p gateway.example.com
#    SendEnv LANG LC_*
#    HashKnownHosts yes
#    GSSAPIAuthentication yes
#    HashKnownHosts yes
#    GSSAPIAuthentication yes
#    GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
    RSAAuthentication yes
    PubKeyAuthentication yes
    ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
    PasswordAuthentication no
    UsePAM no
```

I have then tried restarting the service, rebooting the computer, and everything else that I can think of and yet I can still log into this computer with my password, from multiple other computers.  Here's a dump of the ssh connection:

```
$ ssh -v matthew@server
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/matthew/.ssh/private_key
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
matthew@server's password: 
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
matthew@server's password:
```

The public key connection failed because I renamed my private key, intentionally to make sure it forces password authentication and theoretically fails.  At any rate, it does not and I can not for the life of me figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
I have modified the /etc/ssh/ssh_config files as follows...
```

`ssh_config` is the configuration file for the ssh *client*, not the *server*. To block password authentication on incoming SSH connections, you need to disable the feature in the *server*. The server's configuration file is `sshd_config`, most likely in the `/etc/ssh` directory.

The manual page for `sshd_config` is [here.](http://www.openssh.com/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=sshd_config) You most likely want to set the parameter 
`PasswordAuthentication` to "no".

Comment: Yep, just figured that out and was coming on to answer my own question when I saw your response.  Didn't realize there were different files for the server and client.  Problem is fixed now though.  Thanks!